# How to return to previous position of recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

How to return to previous position of recyclerview when item is clicked and then the user moves back to recyclerview just like Youtube When user watch the video it return to previous item not from top

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Blog,BlogViewHolder>FirebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
            <Blog, BlogViewHolder>( Blog.class,R.layout.blog_row,BlogViewHolder.class,mDatabase)
    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {

            final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getImage());
            viewHolder.setUserimage(getApplicationContext(),model.getUserimage());
            viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
            viewHolder.setLikeBtn(post_key)

            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,post_key,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent singleBlog = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,BlogSingleActivity.class);
                    singleBlog.putExtra("blog_id",post_key);
                    startActivity(singleBlog);

                }
            });
```

how can i implement getAdapterPosition() in this case

Comment: Instead of start activity try dong a start activity for result and pass the position of the item in the recycler view as an intent extra, then from the 2nd activity pass this position variable back which you will get in the on activity result callback, there you can write code to scroll to a certain position in a recycler view.

Comment: @JudeFernandes can you please with code I researched a lot but nothing works for me